# How to run commands and get the output in bash

Tags: bash

I want to run the following command in bash

```
ruby ......
```

The commands outputs the string "Created all things" when successful.

How can I run the command and check the output for the text `Created all things` to make sure it is successful so that I can run other commands using bash?

Comment: Your command should have a exit status of 0 if everything is successful, non-zero if not, so that you don't have to rely on any particular output.

Comment: BTW, if the only way to check whether your program was successful is reading its output, then it was poorly written. A well-behaved UNIX program indicates success or failure through exit status.

Comment: ...so, you could (if your Ruby program were well-behaved) do: `if ruby ....; then echo "Success"; else echo "Failed"; fi`, and not need to have your shell script look at its output at all. And if it's not well-behaved, that's a thing to complain to its authors about.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the output in a variable using the `$(...)` syntax, then do regular bash checks like:

```
output=$(ruby ....)
if [ "$output" = "Created all things" ]; then
    # success, keep going
else
    # failure, clean up
fi
```

Given your comment about wanting to see if it ended with that string, you can use a bash regex instead:

```
if [[ "$output" =~ Created\ all\ things$ ]]; then
...
```

Comment: problem is that is not the only output it returns. The command returns a lot of other output but at the end it returns "Created all things" if successful. So I need a regular expression

Comment: @PotaOnasys see my update that will hopefully address that

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Eric had written, but this will search for the string throughout the entire output instead of just the end.

```
results=$(ruby.......)
 if [[ $(echo ${results} | grep -c "Created all things") != "0" ]] ; then
    echo "Command appears to be successful"
 else
    echo "Command appears to have failed"
 fi
```